# How to debug a class library on Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, debugging, azure-web-app-service, lib

I have a .NET application running in Azure. It has a library linked to it, but its source code is in a separate solution, and I need to debug this library. How do I link this library in Azure, and connect the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

- In .Net Application , Right click on the Reference folder and browse your class library and select the dll file (`YourClassLibraryName.dll`)   from the bin folder of the class library.

[image]

- dll Reference will be added in the .Net Application `Reference` folder.
- Build and re-deploy the .Net Application.
- If you have the project's dependencies, using Visual Studio to deploy (via publish profile) will automatically upload all of the project's dependant projects/ libraries.
- ***Publishing your Solution will  automatically publish your dll's.***
- The bin folder and its contents are copied to the target machine when the project is published.
- After publishing the application,check whether all the files and dll's exists in the bin folder

```cs
Path - Azure Portal=>Azure Web App=>Advanced Tools=>Go=>Debug Console=>CMD=>site=>wwwroot=> bin
```

You can see the referenced dlls with extension `.dll` and `.pdb`

[image]

- In VS, Add the namespace of the class library and  Set breakpoints in your code where you want them.
- To begin debugging, press F5. Visual Studio will identify the module load, load the symbols, and then stop at the breakpoint.

[image]

- In Visual studio => Net Application => In Publish window = >Hosting Settings => Click on Attach Debugger option

[image]

[image]